# Ubuntu Suddenly Completely Wipes From My Hard Drive - Windows11/Ubuntu 22.04 Dual Boot

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive

I just had a terrible moment with my computer. Just days prior I was working on Ubuntu for my robotics courses, I had reset my hard drive in January to perform a Dual Boot and it worked great. Today I went to boot it up once more and it completely left the building. My partition is still there, but Windows says it is 100% free for storage. The boot option is still there in my BIOS Setup, but when I select it I get a critical error saying "no bootable devices found". All my files are definitely corrupted and gone, right? What can I do to prevent this from happening in the future? How did this happen?

Comment: you can boot a live linux and save your date when the filesystem is still there.

Comment: Windows does not understand filesystems that are not microsoft made. chek wit a live session if the data is still there and if so do a boot-repair. Maybe Windows did an update and replace your boot but the one from Microsoft

Comment: Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version over somewhat older ISO with your USB installer  or any working install.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Answer (score 0):

Can't address the dual-boot question, but

1. Always back up your files.
2. In case you didn't do #1, I've had success using Puppy on a live flash drive to access the "inaccessible" partition. Here is a reference article:
   https://www.sysprobs.com/puppy-linux-recover-windows-7-files-boot
3. In case the files are corrupted, you still may be able to recover them  through using the photorec application that is included in the testdisk package. See: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/photorec-recover-deleted-files-in-linux-ubuntu